# Do I need cPanel for a Rails application?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails

I'm migrating a Rails application to a dedicated server. Can it be set up without a cPanel installation? It seems like I could use just Apache and Passenger.

Cheers!

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cPanel isn't needed for anything, it is merely a web interface to make some tasks easier for inexperienced users. You will find that most people over here dislike, as it tends to cause surprises for those who *do* know what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, I figured it was something like that after realising I hadn't used it ever for the VPS install of the same app. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a Rails app to a dedicated server you need:

- a `ruby` interpreter comprehensive of the `gem` command
- the gems `rake` and `bundler`
- a webserver like Apache or Nginx
- a module talking the language of Rails (Rack), can be Passenger or Unicorn or Thin.